# Javascript `this` object == `window` in member function

Tags: javascript

In some of my Javascript objects I find that my `this` pointer is correct - these are `new Func()` -type objects - when created, but in the assigned methods it can be wrong.

```
function Confused() {
   console.log("checking",this==window,"is always false");
   this.method = function() {
       console.log("checking",this==window,"is true for some funcs but not others");
   };
};
```

On some calls to `(new Confused()).method()` - it seems to have lost it's `this` pointer.  The times this happen seem dependent on the function, rather than random; its something in the code around how I'm creating classes that is causing this.

An example is online at http://williame.github.com/barebones.js/ and the member callback [`G3D._file_loaded`](https://github.com/williame/barebones.js/blob/d313f04dceba0b9c9125501661728e1908a2d026/g3d.js#L10) has a wrong `this` pointer when called sometimes.

Why, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Does [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) answer your question?

Comment: The value of `this` is determined by the particular situation of each invocation of a function. It doesn't matter that a function was originally defined as the value of a property of some object - it doesn't matter **at all**.  What matters is the way that the function is called, and that's it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 4 ways to use a function in Javascript
what each of these does is change what the content of `this` is :

- function calls: this = global object (window in browser)
- method calls: this = object it is called from.
- constructor calls: this = new object you are creating.
- call/apply calls: this = object you passed.

In your case `this == window` when you call the function directly (`Confused()`) but if you call using new (`new Confused()`) then it will be the new object you are creating.

Comment: This is the answer that made it clear to me.  My code was passing that method as a callback to another function.  I am really not enjoying learning Javascript; it seems to have strange, pointless gotchas like this at every turn.  Oh well.

Answer (score 4):

The `this` keyword refers to the calling context. It is never *wrong* but it may not be what you would have expected it to be.

You can manually set context when calling a function, if you call it with `.call` or `.apply`.

Furthermore, if a reference to `window` is what you want, why not use `window` instead of `this`? It's a way more reliable means of accessing the window object.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to David Hedlunds explanation, you can "work around" that problem like this:

```
function Confused() {
   var that = this;
   console.log("checking",that==window,"is always false");
   this.method = function() {
       console.log("checking",that==window,"is always false");
   };
};
```

The problem is that the whoever actually invokes your function has control over context of your function. If you do not control the function invocation (that is, if you can't modify the code), than you are stuck with the solution I gave (at least I know of no other way).

While the solution seems a little "hackish", it really isn't if you think about it. It simply harnesses the power given to you by closures :D

Comment: that's the workaround in my code linked.  I'm unhappy with it.