# Javascript difference between calling a function and creating an instance of a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand why an inner function can access a public property of an outer function when the outer function is called directly, but not when it is assigned to a variable?

Example:

```
function outer(x,y){

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    function inner(){
        alert(this.x);       
    }

    inner();
}

outer(1,2); //As expected, alerts 1
var func = outer(1,2) //Also alert 1
var func2 = new outer(1,2); //Alerts undefined
```

One thing I tried was to remove the `this` keyword from `alert(this.x);` and it did work for all three cases.  However, if I do remove the `this` keyword, I'd be accessing the passed in param, not the public variable, which is definitely not the desired action.  Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: Ony use `this` inside the function body, if you intend to invoke it via `new`, or as a method, or via one of the `.call()`/`.apply()`/`.bind()` methods. A function that is invoked regularly via `funcName()` should not use `this`.

Comment: Also, if the JavaScript program runs in strict mode, and a function is invoked via `funcName()`, then `this` will be `undefined`. As a result, property access (e.g. `this.x`) throws a reference error.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you call `outer(1, 2)` like that, `this` is a reference to `window`, so "x" and "y" are effectively global variables. That's why `inner()` can access "x".

When you call `new outer(1, 2)` you have caused `this` (in "outer") to be a reference to a new object. When "inner" is called inside "outer", `this` will still reference `window`, so there's no "x".

The value of `this` is determined for **every** function call, and the value depends only on the particulars of that call. Thus the fact that you call "outer" via `new` has no effect on the interior call to "inner" — because you simply call the function as `inner();`, the value of `this` inside that function will be a reference to `window` (well, the global context, whatever that is).

Here are the ways `this` can be set upon a call to a function:

1. If the function is called via the `new` operator, then `this` will refer to a newly-created object.
2. If the reference to the function is obtained via a property lookup on an object (`foo.someFunction()`), then `this` will be a reference to that object.
3. If the function is called via `.call()` or `.apply()` from the Function prototype, then `this` will refer to the first argument to whichever of those functions was used, coerced to an object value if necessary.
4. If the function is called via a simple "naked" reference, then `this` will refer to the global context (`window` in a browser). *edit* —  Šime Vidas points out in a comment above that in strict mode, this case results in `this` being `null` (which really makes a little more sense, and would avoid the weirdness observed in the OP).

Comment: @JeroenMoons because the call to inner is made in such a way that there's nothing else for it to be.

Comment: Ok so 'this' behaves differently than any other variable? I mean, if you would define a var inside the outside function (but outside the inside function ;)), and used it inside the inside function, it would work, correct?

Comment: Yes: `this` isn't really a variable. It's akin to the Smalltalk concept of "receiver" - in that language, it's a little easier to understand because function  calls are explicitly thought of as message passing, so the "receiver" is the object to which you send a message.

Comment: OK, so is there a way to ensure that inner can access the public variable x of outer?

Comment: @hsalama well if your example code didn't use `this` at all, and instead made `x` and `y` be local variables, then it'd work. Alternatively, that call to `inner()` could be made like this: `inner.call(this)`.

Answer (score 9):

There are 4 ways to use a function in Javascript
what each of these does is change what the content of `this` is :

- function calls: this = global object (window in browser)
- method calls: this = object it is called from.
- constructor calls: this = new object you are creating.
- call/apply calls: this = object you passed.

In your case `this == window` when you call the function directly (`outer()`) but if you call using new (`new outer()`) then it will be the new object you are creating.

basically what I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12091342/82526)

Comment: Ha ha yes I shamelessly stole your "list of scenarios" explanation from that other answer :-)